# regex : Disallow questionmark in website url field

Tags: regex

Clearly i am not a regex specialist but by searching strings i made the following regex work for URL field.

```
(http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?
```

But the problem i have is that people are adding refferal ID's in the url field which i want to block.

For example an URL like:

```
http://www.website.com/subdir/foo?item=234
```

Should be converted to everything before the questionmark:

```
http://www.website.com/subdir/foo
```

I thought the part `[\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]` should hold this string and tried various options by changing parts to `[^?]*` for blocking the `?`, resulting in  `[\w#!:.^?+=&%@!\-\/]` but cannot find the right sequence.

Is something like this possible?

Jasper

Comment: You would break many otherwise valid pages doing that, but you can just remove the `?` from the `[\w#!:......]` part.

Comment: Then again, your `\S+` is far too greedy and would just readily grab anything it can possibly find. You'll need a better way to validate the domain name part of the string.

Comment: why not just look for the "?" and then dump everything after it?  ^(.*)\?.*  >> $1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove URL options marked with a question mark, you can just extract everything in front of the question mark and use just this part.

If you want to do this with regular expression, you can use the following pattern:

```
(https?:\/\/.*?)(?:\?.*)?$
```

And then look for the first group `$1`

- `(https?:\/\/.*?)` matches group of `http://` or `https://` followed by any character with as few characters as possible
- `(?:\?.*)?` It is followed by an optional non-capturing group `(?:)` (you don't want to match this thing) with a question mark and any number of characters afterwards.
- `$` Marks the end of the string. This makes sure, that the first group expands until the end of the string, even if there is no question mark in it.

```js
var regex = /(https?:\/\/.*?)(?:\?.*)?$/;
var url1 = "http://www.google.com/test?parameter=1";
var url2 = "https://www.google.com/?";
var url3 = "https://google.com";

console.log(regex.exec(url1)[1]);
console.log(regex.exec(url2)[1]);
console.log(regex.exec(url3)[1]);
```